# Can you remove/change magic weapon/armor special abilities?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, magic-items, crafting

Say you find a *+4 goblinoid bane rapier*. Nice bonus, but you're not fighting goblinoids. Can you use crafting to remove the *goblinoid bane* special ability, in order to add on something more relevant (or at the very least, so you can just call your weapon a "*+4 rapier*" and save some syllables at the table)?

Comment: If your whole group knows it is a +4 Goblin Bane Rapier, why can't you just call it your rapier? Un less you have other rapiers, I think everyone would understand.

Comment: I *know* I have answered this question before, but for the life of me I can’t find it. Very frustrating.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know you can only add features to items, not change them or remove them. Nowhere in the crafting rules have I seen anything saying that you can or how it is done.

Answer (score 1):

#### There are two main methods for "disenchanting" a magic item.

Both are rather permanent.

1. [Mordenkainen's Disjunction](https://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/magesDisjunction.htm) - This spell (known as Mage's Disjunction in the SRD) will completely disenchant (and destroy) one or more magic items and/or effects permanently.
2. Artificer's 5th level *Retain Essence* class feature - This ability allows an artificer to 'deconstruct' a magic item, and recover some of the XP used in crafting it as Craft Reserve points. The item is destroyed.

In either case, you will need to make a new item from scratch, but at least with the Artificer's route, you'll recapture the XP needed to do so. [Other methods are available](http://minmaxforum.com/index.php?topic=1000) to reduce the time and cost (and even auto-craft) the item you actually want.

---

Your DM may optionally allow a homebrew modification to the Artificer's *Retain Essence* class feature to permit it to target specific abilities instead of the whole item, which should not unbalance most campaigns, especially if the Artificer in question is an NPC.